# Tikz array as argument

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

## Problem

I'm drawing flow diagrams in Tikz, and they basically include a header, followed by a list of flow components set below an arrow. I've written functions to take arguments in Tikz before, but I'm wondering if there's any way to take in a "list" of arguments and loop through these with a for loop of some sort.

I've tried searching for similar items on google, but haven't gotten very far as I'm not exactly sure how to phrase what I'm looking for.

### Pseudocode

```
\newcommand{\FlowPipe}[3][FlowPipe]{ %first argument is x co-ord, second is array of text
    \newcounter{i}
    \setcounter{i}{0}
    \draw[->] (#1,0) -- (#1+3,0);
    \foreach\argtext in {#2}{
         \node (#1,i) {\argtext};
         \stepcounter{i}
    }
}
```

Basically, for each item in the array, it should add a node at some specified distance below and put the text of that item there.

Comment: Could illustrate what you want to do with some pseudocode example. Also, can TikZ's `\foreach` do what you want, or do you need something more complicated?

Comment: added, I'm not sure that'll help but I hope it does.

Comment: It helps, because it shows what you want to do and gives a starting point for a solution. I'm not sure though what you intend to do with the first argument (the one you specified as optional with default parameter 'FlowPipe').

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TikZ `\foreach` macro is handy for situations like this:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\FlowPipe[2]{ %first argument is x co-ord, second is array of text
    \draw[->] (#1,0) -- ({#1+3},0);
    \foreach[count=\i] \argtext in {#2} {
         \node[anchor=south west] at (#1,{\i-0.9}) {\argtext};
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\FlowPipe{1}{{first text},{second text},{with, comma}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

See section 56 ("Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement") in the TikZ/PGF v2.10 manual. The `count` option was introduced in TikZ v2.10, so you might need to update TikZ/PGF. The reason for using `count` instead of LaTeX counters in that counters are defined globally, and I do not know how to easily get local counters (otherwise a second call to the macro will produce an `already defined` error).

Comment: You shouldn't need the braces around `first text` and `second text`, since they don't contain commas.

Comment: @Antal You are right. On the other hand they do not hurt and might make the code more readable.